# How to select first Descendant with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this snippet

```
       <li class="overview">
            <a href="...">
                <span class="txt">Link 1</span>  
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="navBI">
                    <a href="...">
                       <span class="txt">Link 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

And I want to select **only Link 1** but I cannot find the answer.
I tried `.overview .txt` but it also choose Link 2.
I am not so familiar with the CSS Combinators.

I also tried `.overview > a > .txt`.

Is there something I miss?

Comment: How about assigning a unique class for link 1?

Comment: `.overview > a > .txt` appears to be working perfectly fine here already for what you want. Not sure what the actual issue is supposed to be now? Provide a proper [mre] if you are having trouble with this.

Comment: What exactly is the difference if I use `.overview > a:first-child > .txt`?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <li class="overview">
            <a href="...">
                <span id=“text” class="txt">Link 1</span>  
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="navBI">
                    <a href="...">
                       <span class="txt">Link 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

#text {
Stuff: stuff;
}
```

Could you use an id?  Is it being generated in .js?

Comment: No I cannot change anything unfortunately...